# Dynamically adding a row at the bottom of a table using onblur event in Javascript (with out button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

My requirement is, I have a table with 3 columns and  5 rows. When I am using the last  row, dynamically a new row should be added after the last row and when I am using newly created row again a new row should be added dynamically at last and so.. but  the problem is we should not use buttons for adding a rows, instead we have to use onblur or onchange events. Can anyone suggest me the solution for the above problem?

Comment: Do you have any code or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `focus` event, so that you add the row when you start to use the last row? You can add a delegate to the table, so that the event works even for newly added rows:

```
$(function(){
  $('#TheTable').on('focus', 'input', function(){
    if ($(this).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
      $('#TheTable').append('<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>');
    }
  });
});
```

Demio: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/2mcp3/

Answer (score 0):

The following function can be used to add a row to a table.

```
function addrow() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tableid');
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    row.id = 'row'+table.rows.length; //ID the rows however you like, make each one unique though.
}
```

You could consider an `onClick` for the table row to add a new row. You could add something like this to the `addrow()` function: `row.onClick = addrow();`, but if you only want the last row to do this, make sure you use `document.getElementById('otherrow').onClick = "";` to reset the old row with CSS ID "otherrow".

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link, There I am using a button click event for calling the function. Insted of that you can simply change it into onblur function of any text fields or something. Hope it will work. [Check this answer link](http://adesignersnotes.blogspot.in/2012/02/dynamically-adding-rows-and-styles-to.html)